# jQuery event.target.id does not always(!) get id on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `event.target.id` several times on a page, but in one particular case it just doesn't work. It seems to return either `null` or an empty string.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $modal = $('body');
  var $imgID = 'idcodeoftheimage';

  var $after2 = '<div class="w3-bar w3-bottom w3-center buttonbar"><div class="buttons"><a href="javascript:;" id="' + $imgID + '" class="flag"><i class="">Flag</i></a></div></div>';
  $modal.append($after2);

  $('body').on('click', '.flag', function(event) {
    var $id = event.target.id;
    console.log($id);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

The exact same line of code works elsewhere so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Why are you giving the same ID to multiple elements? IDs should be unique.

Comment: Can you turn the code in your question into an executable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can try it out?

Comment: Javascript isn't PHP, you don't need to start variables with `$`.

Comment: ...wait, you have `<i>` elements inside those `<a>` elements, and they don't have an ID.

Comment: @squint But the `<i>` elements don't have `class="flag"` so they shouldn't matter.

Comment: The page uses a lot of modals to display images in a lightbox-style. The IDs are equal to the filename; I use it for processing purposes. I just find it to be extremely manageble compared to a more conform solution using passing parameters and such. As far as I know, non-unique IDs are considered dirty but not explicitly wrong..?

Comment: @Barmar: Doesn't matter. The `event.target` is the deepest element clicked.

Comment: @traxx2012 Instead of abusing IDs like that, use a `data` attribute.

Comment: @squint So he should be using `event.currentTarget` instead?

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, or `this`, assuming the `.flag` element is the one being targeted. This is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: The `event.currentTarget` was the solution. I didn't find the question mine is a duplicate of because I didn't search for the right terms since I didn't understand the problem well enough. Sorry for the duplicate and thanks for the help!

Comment: Just FYI, you'll probably have much better luck using google to search for answers than StackOverflow's search tool, especially if you target `site:stackoverflow.com` specifically. My search term was [site:stackoverflow.com javascript id is blank](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+id+is+blank), which brought me to the duplicate.